# Change terminal and vim colors by time of day

Tags: vim, terminal, gnome-terminal

I would like to have my vim and terminal color schemes automatically change based on the time of day if possible. This way I could have a night theme and a day theme that would be comfortable to look at. I am using the gnome-terminal on linux.